# Not able to create docker image getting 51 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

*Error in console:*

```
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 17.* from BP_JVM_VERSION
[INFO]     [creator]       BellSoft Liberica JRE 17.0.7: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/17.0.7+7/bellsoft-jre17.0.7+7-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency jre
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/17.0.7+7/bellsoft-jre17.0.7+7-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/17.0.7+7/bellsoft-jre17.0.7+7-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/17.0.7+7/bellsoft-jre17.0.7+7-linux-amd64.tar.gz": dial tcp: lookup github.com: i/o timeout
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  36.001 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-04T12:03:15+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.15:build-image (default-cli) on project demo: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.15:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

from spring initializer website I am creating a simple spring boot app with only spring web as dependency with spring version 3, java version 17.0.8, maven version 3.9.4 to test my docker is working or not but getting this error(screenshot attached) while running  `mavnw spring-boot:build-image`.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.15</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>
                            ${project.artifactId}:${project.version}
                        </name>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried also with spring boot 2.7.15. but problem is same.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Post your Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the beltsoft JRE layer is not getting downloaded.
It's possible it's an intermittent network issue, or maybe the docker image got removed / renamed (if it's an old version for example)

Check the documentation https://hub.docker.com/r/bellsoft/liberica-openjre-alpine and verify the Dockerfile is using the recommended image.

It seems that https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/17.0.7%2B7/bellsoft-jdk17.0.7+7-linux-amd64.tar.gz does exist, so maybe it's a network issue after all...

Comment: Sorry I am new to Docker but what I understand is if we are using buildpacks we no need to specifically define docker file, please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your network settings to use the IP addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as your DNS servers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).